# Upgrade clojure to the new version

Tags: clojure, upgrade

I want to upgrade my clojure from the version 1.6.0 to 1.7.0. How can i do this? I can not exactly remember how i installed it, but most probably using leiningen.

Comment: Clojure is just a dependency in your `project.clj`, the only thing you need to do to update your Clojure version is change it there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using Leiningen, Clojure itself is just a dependency on your `project.clj`. You can specify the version there.

So it is easy to go back and forth between Clojure versions and you can use different versions for different projects without any conflicts.

The relevant Leiningen documentation can be found [here](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/stable/doc/TUTORIAL.md#projectclj)

Comment: but what if i want to have the 1.7. version also in my repl?

Comment: as long as you start the REPL in the project directory tree via `lein repl` you should get the correct Clojure version (as specified in `project.clj`)